# Is there a way to output the contents of the currently running script?

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to use a command in my script that will print the literal text contents of the script itself.

I tried using `cat $(pwd)/$(basename "$0")`, but doesn't work.
Anyone figured out how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's dissect this command:

```
cat $(pwd)/$(basename "$0")
```

- `$(pwd)` expands to the current directory that you are in.
- `$(basename "$0")` expands to the filename of the running script.
- (Also, these should really be quoted, because they would fail with paths with whitespace etc. in them.)

Hence, if you run the script from the same directory, then this should work.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat $(pwd)/$(basename "$0")
$ ./test.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat $(pwd)/$(basename "$0")
```

However, if the current directory is *not* the directory where the script is located, this command will fail.

```
$ cd /home
$ /tmp/test.sh
cat: /home/test.sh: No such file or directory
```

You can see that the `pwd` in the command is looking in the *current* directory, not the one where the script is.

To solve, simply use `$0` instead.

```
cat "$0"
```

This is simpler, and will work no matter what the current directory is.

Comment: It's work just like what you said, thx   never thought something like that